# Passing unknown number of values to PowerShell script parameter?

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I am familiar with how to accept parameters or arguments from the command line and pass them to PowerShell:

```
powershell.exe -file myscript.ps1 -COMPUTER server1 -DATA abcd
```

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$computer,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$data
)
```

That’s fine, but what if the `$computer` argument is more than one item and of an unknown number of items?  For example:

```
Powershell.exe -file myscript.ps1 -COMPUTER server1, server2, server3 -DATA abcd
```

Here we do not know how many `$computer` items there will be. There will always be one, but there could be 2, 3, 4, etc.  How is something like this best achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the parameter `[String]$Computer` accept multiple strings (or an `array`) by using `[String[]]$Computer` instead.

**Example:**

```
Function Get-Foo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [String[]]$Computer,

       [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
       [String]$Data
    )

    "We found $(($Computer | Measure-Object).Count) computers"
}

Get-Foo -Computer a, b, c -Data yes

# We found 3 computers

Get-Foo -Computer a, b, c, d, e, f -Data yes

# We found 6 computers
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify this in the parameter definition. Change from `[String]` to an array of strings `[String[]]`

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string[]]$computer,

   [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$data
)
```